# Does Iron Will cover supernatural rolls?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

Iron will (GMCRU) grants you the ability to use your Resolve instead of the usual +3 when using willpower to contest or resist a social interaction.

**Does this include resisting or contesting supernatural social  interactions?**

I ask mainly as there seems to be a separate merit with that in mind, Indomitable (also GMCRU), which works slightly differently, in that it only helps against the supernatural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, it does not include supernatural interactions

Iron Will resolves around social interactions (see the Social Manoeuvring rules on p188 and later), while Indomitable references "The powers of the 
supernatural have little bearing on her behavior." (rather confusing that they describe the character as having an Iron Will), or even clearer:

> Any time a supernatural creature uses 
>   a power to influence your character’s thoughts or emotions, 
>   add two dice to the dice pool to contest it.

In short:

- Iron Will helps in Social Maneuvering situations (you motivate somebody else to do something for you)
- Indomitable helps against mental influences from various sources

Some examples:

- If a Vampire Dominates you, you better have Indomitable.
- If he just Persuasions you, you better have Iron Will.
- If he uses Majesty while trying to Persuasion you, you better have both .

Do note that his Persuasion attempt will have various steps,  in one of these steps he can augment himself by using a supernatural ability (such as Majesty or Dominate) to give himself a boost (or just trying to shortcut the entire thing by using Majesty 2). Indomitable will help against the use of the supernatural ability, while Iron Will boosts your defense against his entire Persuasion attempt.

Comment: The only situation I was thinking about was number three in your list.  Glad to hear you think that counts. Odd that you say it doesn't though...

Comment: I think that's clearer? I just don't remember the part in the GMCRU that says Iron Will only works for social manoeuvring. I'll have to check tonight